# NSString type with index

Tags: json, xcode4.5

I have created Author class like this :

```
@interface Author : NSObject{
NSString *authorID;
NSString *email;
NSString *userName;
NSString *password;
NSString *jenisKelamin;
NSString *alamat;
NSString *kota;
NSString *telepon;
NSString *pekerjaan;
NSString *nama;
NSString *tanggalDaftar;
NSString *status;
NSString *lastLogin;
NSString *publishPhoto;
NSString *komentar;
NSString *balasKomentar;
NSString *newsLetter;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *authorID;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *userName;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *password;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *jenisKelamin;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *alamat;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *kota;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *telepon;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *pekerjaan;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *nama;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *tanggalDaftar;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *status;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *lastLogin;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *publishPhoto;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *komentar;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *balasKomentar;
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *newsLetter;

@end
```

and read json like this :

```
imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSError *jsonParsingError = nil;
id myJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonParsingError];
NSDictionary *imageList;
for (int i=0; i<[myJson count]; i++) {
    imageList=[myJson objectAtIndex:i];
    currentImage = [ImageList alloc];
    currentImage.imageID=[imageList valueForKey:@"id"];
    currentImage.tanggal=[imageList valueForKey:@"tanggal"];
    currentImage.judul=[imageList valueForKey:@"judul"];
    currentImage.namaFile=[imageList valueForKey:@"nama_file"];
    currentImage.deskripsi=[imageList valueForKey:@"deskripsi"];
    currentImage.user=[imageList valueForKey:@"user"];
    currentImage.status=[imageList valueForKey:@"status"];
    currentImage.views=[imageList valueForKey:@"views"];
    currentImage.rating=[imageList valueForKey:@"rating"];
    currentImage.totalRating=[imageList valueForKey:@"total_rating"];
    currentImage.totalPerating=[imageList valueForKey:@"total_perating"];
    currentImage.imageThemeID=[imageList valueForKey:@"tema"];
    currentImage.bayesianRating=[imageList valueForKey:@"bayesian_rating"];
    currentImage.imageURL=[imageList valueForKey:@"img_url"];
    NSDictionary *authorDict = [imageList objectForKey:@"author"];
    currentImage.author = [[[Author alloc] init] autorelease];
    currentImage.author.authorID = [authorDict valueForKey:@"id"];
    currentImage.author.email = [authorDict valueForKey:@"email"];
    currentImage.author.userName = [authorDict valueForKey:@"username"];
    currentImage.author.password = [authorDict valueForKey:@"password"];
    currentImage.author.jenisKelamin = [authorDict valueForKey:@"jenis_kelamin"];
    currentImage.author.alamat = [authorDict valueForKey:@"alamat"];
    currentImage.author.kota = [authorDict valueForKey:@"kota"];
    currentImage.author.telepon = [authorDict valueForKey:@"telepon"];
    currentImage.author.pekerjaan = [authorDict valueForKey:@"pekerjaan"];
    currentImage.author.nama = [authorDict valueForKey:@"nama"];
    currentImage.author.tanggalDaftar = [authorDict valueForKey:@"tanggal_daftar"];
    currentImage.author.status = [authorDict valueForKey:@"status"];
    currentImage.author.lastLogin = [authorDict valueForKey:@"last_login"];
    [imageArray addObject:currentImage];
    [currentImage release];
    return self;
}
```

But if I try to get the value using :

```
jsonImage =[[JSONReader alloc]loadImageList:newURL];
    ImageList *currentImage;
    currentImage = [[jsonImage imageArray]objectAtIndex:0];
    [jsonTheme release];
    if([jsonImage.imageArray count]>0){
        NSLog(@"getting image starting");
        NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:currentImage.imageURL];
        NSLog(@"image URL from array : %@", currentImage.imageURL);
        NSData *imageData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        imgTemp = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
        self.imgImage.image = imgTemp;
        NSLog(@"getting image stop");
        lblDate.text = currentImage.tanggal;
        lblDescription.text = currentImage.deskripsi;
        lblSummary.text = currentImage.judul;
        Author *currentAuthor = currentImage.author;
        lblUser.text = currentAuthor.userName;

        [currentImage release];
    }


lblUser.text = currentTheme.author.userName; the result of lblUser is null.
```

when I tried to debug, the value of userName have index :

```
currentAuthor   Author *    0x071a9a20
NSObject    NSObject    
authorID    NSString *  0x0753e700
[0] id  0x071a4ad0
[0] id  
email   NSString *  0x075403a0
[0] id  0x071a58e0
userName    NSString *  0x0753fef0
[0] id  0x071a5930
```

can you tell me how to get currentAuthor values ?

Comment: It maybe an idea to cut the code you have posted down to small example. Especially as you are only asking how to find the value of an item.

Answer (score 0):

I think , while releasing currentImage . value of author also changed.
Please do the following changes and try it

```
Author *currentAuthor =[ currentImage.author copy];
```